# How to find multiplication of the number elements of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiplication

I have array `a = [1,2,3,4]`.

I would like to get the final number `t = 1*2*3*4 = 24`, which is multiplication of each element to each other, starting from 0 position up to last element of the array?
I tried this one:

```
for(var i=1; i < a.length: i++){
   t = a[i] * a[i-1];
   t *= t;
}
```

but it is giving wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

```
t = 1;
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
 t *= a[i];
}
```

or...

```
t = a.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a * b;
}, 1);
```

Comment: in reduce you can avoid `,1` - result would be same :-)

Comment: thank you very much it helped me. But just to multiply all elements starting from 0 I had to change from var i=1 to var i=0; So it looks like `t = 1;
for(var i=0;i<a.length:i++){
 t *= a[i];
}`. Great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
mul = 1;
for(var i=1;i<a.length:i++){
mul =mul * a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, just use this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4], t = 1; 

for(var item of a){
   t *= item
}
```